# SSH-Connection "Permission denied" after change of IP-Addresses

Tags: linux, windows, networking, ssh, permissions

a couple of hours ago I changed the IP-Address of my Windows-PC and my Raspberry Pi. Up until then I was able to connect to the Pi via SSH without any problems. Now, when I try to connect, I get the error message, that someone is trying "something nasty" and that I should contact my Network Administrator.

So I made a backup of my "known-hosts" file and created an empty one. When I connect now via SSH through Windows-Terminal I get the following Output:

[image: Output]

I have no idea what this is supposed to tell me, nor what should I do. I already flashed the Pi, yet to no avail. No matter if I reset the network-configuration of my PC or the Pi or both in the router config, the error-messages remain the same.

Comment: What’s happening on the server as you attempt to connect? It’s unusual and insecure to allow root to connect directly over SSH are you sure the server configuration allows for that? The verbose client output suggests the client wasn’t able to use a key and the password was rejected

Comment: I can't check what's happening since I can't connect.

Comment: Without know what’s happening on the server side I can’t help. [The “dev/tty” message suggests that the public key is improperly formatted.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416166/cant-establish-ssh-connection-debug1-read-passphrase-cant-open-dev-tty-n)

Comment: What OS was your Raspberry Pi running?

Comment: Ubuntu Server 23.04 (64-bit)

Comment: @Fabsen Instead of posting screenshots of terminal output, please copy/paste the terminal output into a code box within a question/answer _(please see the question mark on the edit toolbar when writing a question/answer)_  - if the copied output exceeds the 30k character limit, please paste it on [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com) and link to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Not surprisingly it was something I did.

The errormessage with all the "@"-symbols telling me someone is trying "something nasty" was quite clear and also deleting the contents of the "known_hosts"-file.
But then I made the mistake trying to log in with "root", what really is disabled apparently. Also I just realized that you cannot login with a lowercase username after the first boot-procedure.

Logging in with user "test" with password "test" didn't work, but logging in with user "Test" and password "test" did.

So I guess I learned something new.

Answer (score 1):

**The message**

> someone is trying "something nasty"

is a result of changing the IP of the server.

This typically appears, when the user's `known_hosts` at the client has information about the server, but parts of the information stored differ from the current connection parameters (i.e. other IP by same host key or vice versa) that identify the server.

I think, your grayed-out hostname is not a hostname but an IP-address. Changing the IP of the server triggered the message. Using a hostname would have prevented this.
*(to tell if you're using an IP or hostname is relevant, so preferably you substitute the information instead of eliminating it for privacy)*

By eliminating the original `known_hosts` file this error should have been gone and replaced by the "first contact"-message, asking for adding the new host-key to `known_hosts`.

*=> This is not part of your current login problem.*

---

**The login problem**

The debug log tells:

- you are at a Windows client that uses OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1
- Allowed authentication methods are `publickey` and `password`
- Your client has stored several IDs that could be used to login via "publickey authentication" (what is being tried)
  But the account at the server does not have the pendant to at least one of the available IDs in `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` and all of the five request fail.
  => Either you never have used this  authentication method or by re-flashing your Pi server you eliminated an already present `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`, killing your possibility to use this request method.
- As public key authentication fails, SSH tries the *"password authentication"*, but runs into an error:
  `read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory`
  => Obviously *"OpenSSH for Windows"* does know where to output the Login dialog and finally the login fails after the three allowed tries.

---

**Subsumming** the current information in your question I'm quite sure:

Before your fatal changes you connected via *publickey authentication*.
**Reason:** As you didn't change relevant settings at the client and  the *password authentication* fails, this problem must already have been present before your fatal changes. But as you have not been aware of the problem the other possible authentication must have been used.

Due to the loss of the original `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` at the server, the server can't authorize your access via *publickey authentication* and all login efforts fail.

**Solutions**

1. Repair your password authentication handling at *OpenSSH for Windows*.
   As you did not give any information about how you initiate the ssh connection, there can't be a proper answer.
   Possibly you use a GUI-tool to connect. Then it might enough to just open a terminal window and start the session by command line.
   *=> You should create a new question with more details to solve this particular problem.*

or

2. Restore or recreate the `root/.ssh/authorized_keys` at the server.
   To add a key to `authorized_keys`:

   1. Copy only the public key of a key pair present (or newly created) at your Windows client `C:\Users\???\.ssh\` to your server.
   2. At the server add the public key to the user's `authorized_keys` :
      `cat <public_key_file> >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
   3. Test the login

For the variant 2: If you have difficulties to physically access the server's local console you might want to download a Live Linux and install it to an USB stick to connect to the server via password authentication for re-applying the public key.

---

Please note: As *Ramhound* already mentioned using the user *root* for a remote connection is a bad idea. Better you take a regular user and use `sudo` to obtain root privileges.